# Core Data - Editing, Incrementing and Saving Attribute to already exisiting Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, nsnumber

Ok, so i'm new to CoreData and using NSNumber (about a Day) and I watched a tutorial on CoreData and managed to store a number of different Achievements in coreData using the same entity which I called "Achievement" but now I am trying to fetch the data based on a name given to search for a specific "achievement" and edit its attribute.

```
func addOneToAchievement(AchName: String) {

    let getDataRequest:NSFetchRequest<Achievement> = Achievement.fetchRequest()
    getDataRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "theSearchName == %@" , AchName)

    do {

        let searchResults = try CoreDatabaseContoller.getContext().fetch(getDataRequest)

        //print("number of results: \(searchResults.count)")

        for result in searchResults as [Achievement] {

           // print("\(result.theName!) \(result.theDescription!) is \(result.theImage!) \(result.aAmount!) / \(result.aNeededAmount!) is \(result.aStage!)")

            result.aAmount! += 1

            if result.aAmount! == result.aNeededAmount {

                 result.theImage! = "diamonds2"
                 result.aNeededAmount! = 100
                 result.aStage! = 2

            }
        }
    }

    catch {

        print("ERROR: \(error)")

    }
}
```

But I run into a problem, for the amount attribute of my entity is an NSNumber and have found that I can't increment it by the usual syntax of

```
result.Amount! += 1
```

How can I increment the NSNumber of result.Amount! and then save it along with all the other attributes that I have changed of that certain achievement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have always use standard Swift `Int` types for managed Core Data properties. In my experience the `NSManagedObject` subclasses have automatically provided me with this, but if it's generating `NSNumber` for you there may be a simple way to change it (I haven't done Core Data in Xcode 8 yet).

Anyway, `NSNumber` is just a wrapper around a number, so you can get the actual value out via `intValue`.

```
let amount = result.aAmount!.intValue
a = NSNumber(value: amount + 1)
```

After you've changed everything (provided that the changes have happened on `NSManagedObject` subclasses and properties marked `@NSManged`), you can save by calling `save()` on the context.

```
do {
    try CoreDatabaseContoller.getContext().save()
} catch {
    // Error on Save
}
```